# getting token as cookie from spring boot not accessible in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cookies

cookie does show in browser however cannot be accessed using $cookie.get('io'). What am I missing. I also tried $timeout with 5 seconds delay. I tried to see in headers() but this token does not show there.

Code:

```
$http({
              url: 'http://localhost:8081/api/v1/login',
              method: 'POST',
              data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                    REQUEST_TYPE: requestType
                }), // Make sure to inject the service you choose to the controller
              headers: {

                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' // Note the appropriate header
              }
            }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

//10 seconds delay
        $timeout( function(){
           var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('io');
            alert(favoriteCookie);
        }, 5000 );

        //time
        var time = 0;

        //timer callback
        var timer = function() {
            if( time < 5000 ) {
                time += 1000;
                $timeout(timer, 1000);
            }
        }

        //run!!
        $timeout(timer, 1000);       




                //console.log(response.headers('set-cookie'));

                callback(response = { success: true });
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                callback(response = { success: false });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the cookie you are trying to get is not tagged as httpOnly.

> When you tag a cookie with the HttpOnly flag, it tells the browser
>   that this particular cookie should only be accessed by the server. Any
>   attempt to access the cookie from client script is strictly forbidden.
>   Of course, this presumes you have: A modern web browser. A browser
>   that actually implements HttpOnly correctly.

Answer (score 0):

it was autogenerated cookie. the cookie which i was trying to access did not appear in the browser. I had to make some code modifications in angularjs to get the cookie into browser. I had to include a parameter "withCredentials:true," in the http request. As soon as I did it my cookie appeared in the browser. Now my http request look like this.

```
$http({
                  url: 'http:localhost/login',
                  method: 'POST',
                  data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
                        username: username,
                        password: password,
                        REQUEST_TYPE: requestType
                    }), // Make sure to inject the service you choose to the controller
                  withCredentials:true,
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 

                  }
                }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    callback(response = { success: true });
                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    callback(response = { success: false });
                });



            }
```